# ubuntu-gnome-desktop background image on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 14.04, ubuntu-gnome

Hello I am trying to set desktop background image. I am executing following instruction

'DISPLAY=:1 gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri file:///home/techy/Desktop/desktop_bg.jpg'

I am getting the following error.

'dconf-WARNING **: failed to commit changes to dconf: Error spawning command line 'dbus-launch --autolaunch=b8bff160f4304a51b2ae82dc9cc26ca7 --binary-syntax --close-stderr': Child process exited with code 1'

Any reference to solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Best,

You could use:

> dconf write "/org/gnome/desktop/background/picture-uri" "'file:///home/YOUR_USER/bg.png'"

Comment: Not working. Its not giving error but not setting the image.